# pandas's resample with fill_method: Need to know data from which row was copied?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use resample method to fill the gaps in timeseries data. But I also want to know which row was used to fill the missed data.

This is my input series.

```
In [28]: data
Out[28]: 
Date
2002-09-09    233.25
2002-09-11    233.05
2002-09-16    230.25
2002-09-18    230.10
2002-09-19    230.05
Name: Price
```

With resample, I will get this

```
In [29]: data.resample("D", fill_method='bfill')
Out[29]: 
Date
2002-09-09    233.25
2002-09-10    233.05
2002-09-11    233.05
2002-09-12    230.25
2002-09-13    230.25
2002-09-14    230.25
2002-09-15    230.25
2002-09-16    230.25
2002-09-17    230.10
2002-09-18    230.10
2002-09-19    230.05
Freq: D
```

I am looking for

```
Out[29]: 
Date
2002-09-09    233.25  2002-09-09
2002-09-10    233.05  2012-09-11
2002-09-11    233.05  2012-09-11
2002-09-12    230.25  2012-09-16
2002-09-13    230.25  2012-09-16
2002-09-14    230.25  2012-09-16
2002-09-15    230.25  2012-09-16
2002-09-16    230.25  2012-09-16
2002-09-17    230.10  2012-09-18  
2002-09-18    230.10  2012-09-18
2002-09-19    230.05  2012-09-19
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After converting the `Series` to a `DataFrame`, copy the index into it's own column.  (`DatetimeIndex.format()` is useful here as it returns a string representation of the index, rather than Timestamp/datetime objects.)

```
In [510]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [511]: df['OrigDate'] = df.index.format()

In [513]: df
Out[513]: 
             Price    OrigDate
Date                          
2002-09-09  233.25  2002-09-09
2002-09-11  233.05  2002-09-11
2002-09-16  230.25  2002-09-16
2002-09-18  230.10  2002-09-18
2002-09-19  230.05  2002-09-19
```

For resampling without aggregation, there is a helper method `asfreq()`.

```
In [528]: df.asfreq("D", method='bfill')
Out[528]: 
             Price    OrigDate
2002-09-09  233.25  2002-09-09
2002-09-10  233.05  2002-09-11
2002-09-11  233.05  2002-09-11
2002-09-12  230.25  2002-09-16
2002-09-13  230.25  2002-09-16
2002-09-14  230.25  2002-09-16
2002-09-15  230.25  2002-09-16
2002-09-16  230.25  2002-09-16
2002-09-17  230.10  2002-09-18
2002-09-18  230.10  2002-09-18
2002-09-19  230.05  2002-09-19
```

This is effectively short-hand for the following, where `last()` is invoked on the intermediate `DataFrameGroupBy` objects.

```
In [529]: df.resample("D", how='last', fill_method='bfill')
Out[529]: 
             Price    OrigDate
Date                          
2002-09-09  233.25  2002-09-09
2002-09-10  233.05  2002-09-11
2002-09-11  233.05  2002-09-11
2002-09-12  230.25  2002-09-16
2002-09-13  230.25  2002-09-16
2002-09-14  230.25  2002-09-16
2002-09-15  230.25  2002-09-16
2002-09-16  230.25  2002-09-16
2002-09-17  230.10  2002-09-18
2002-09-18  230.10  2002-09-18
2002-09-19  230.05  2002-09-19
```